# Android Studio gif effect on images

Tags: image, android-studio, blink

Good night everyone.

I am trying to make a GIF effect on two images. 
So, when I load the page, an image A appears and in the next second, it changes to image B. Like a blink or a GIF. 
In resume, I enter the screen and load Image A, then blink and turn to Image B, then blink again and go back to Image A and so on, like a looping. I don't know if I was clear, but whoever can help me, I appreciate it.

Thanks!